# Cannot update Date field - MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My webpage has a date field which uses javascript calendar. The format of the date field on web page is MM/DD/YYYY. When the user enters all information and hits submit, all fields except the corresponding field of Date gets updated. Here are details:

HTML:

```
 <tr>
      <td><label><font color="red">*</font>Date:</label></td>
      <td><input name= "Date" value="Select Date" id="popupDatepicker"></td>
 </tr>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
      $sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (...., USER_DATE, ...) VALUES (...., '$_POST[Date]', ...)"
     ....
?>
```

MySQL: `USER_DATE: DATETIME datatype.`

When a new record in inserted, the USER_DATE shows `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as value even when the Date field is populated on the UI side.

Can anyone please guide me as to the issue here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MM/DD/YYYY` is not the datetime format that MySQL uses.

Try this...

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

#### Example

```
$date = '02/07/2011';

$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

var_dump($sqlDate); // string(10) "2011-02-07"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/ntqpuFyt).

Answer (score 3):

When inserting a date to a MySQL datetime field, your must use `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

As a sidenote : you must escape strings, using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`][1] or [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`][2], depending on the set of functions you are using, to prevent [SQL Injections][3] !

Answer (score 1):

Change the date format after submitting the form.

Mysql accept date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the standard `DATETIME` format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` you can use a `TIMESTAMP` which is an integer with the number of seconds passed since `Jan 01, 1970` or you could also use a `VARCHAR` where you insert what you want.

My opinion is to go for the `TIMESTAMP` since afterwards you can format it as you like with php's date functions.

Comment: [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) has possibly undesirable side-effects, including implicit timezone conversions and (now-optional) additional *magic* behavior that can be asked for.  Plain old [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) columns should be used unless you *want* the timezone conversions or *need* the magic.  Both columns provide the same, exact data otherwise.